# Al ejecutar el comando " npm run build " me da este error

Tags: javascript, nodejs

## **esto es lo que aparece en la consola**

=============================================

he realizado correctamente los comandos "git init", "git add ." y posteriormente al ejecutar " npm run build", para que se cree la carpeta "Dist", me sale este error y me veo truncado debido a que estoy realizando un curso de Javascript.

```js
PS C:\Users\Hogar\Desktop\javascript\curso javascript nuevo\04-Todo> npm run build

> webpack-inicial@1.0.0 build C:\Users\Hogar\Desktop\javascript\curso javascript nuevo\04-Todo
> webpack --config webpack.prod.js

Hash: 10034ed2d41960d522c1
Version: webpack 4.41.5
Time: 1811ms
Built at: 16/06/2020 13:58:35
 1 asset
Entrypoint main = main.56b380741243de702b85.js
[0] ./src/index.js 3.62 KiB {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]

ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Package exports for 'C:\Users\Hogar\Desktop\javascript\curso javascript nuevo\04-Todo\node_modules\@babel\helper-compilation-targets' do not define a '.' subpath
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:419:17)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:492:20)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:693:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:19)
    at require (C:\Users\Hogar\Desktop\javascript\curso javascript nuevo\04-Todo\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hogar\Desktop\javascript\curso javascript nuevo\04-Todo\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\lib\debug.js:8:33)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\Hogar\Desktop\javascript\curso javascript nuevo\04-Todo\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1011:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:822:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:19)
    at require (C:\Users\Hogar\Desktop\javascript\curso javascript nuevo\04-Todo\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hogar\Desktop\javascript\curso javascript nuevo\04-Todo\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\lib\index.js:11:14)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\Hogar\Desktop\javascript\curso javascript nuevo\04-Todo\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1011:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:822:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:19)
    at require (C:\Users\Hogar\Desktop\javascript\curso javascript nuevo\04-Todo\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at requireModule (C:\Users\Hogar\Desktop\javascript\curso javascript nuevo\04-Todo\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:165:12)
    at loadPreset (C:\Users\Hogar\Desktop\javascript\curso javascript nuevo\04-Todo\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:83:17)
    at createDescriptor (C:\Users\Hogar\Desktop\javascript\curso javascript nuevo\04-Todo\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:154:9)
    at C:\Users\Hogar\Desktop\javascript\curso javascript nuevo\04-Todo\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:109:50
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createDescriptors (C:\Users\Hogar\Desktop\javascript\curso javascript nuevo\04-Todo\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:109:29)
    at createPresetDescriptors (C:\Users\Hogar\Desktop\javascript\curso javascript nuevo\04-Todo\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:101:10)
    at presets (C:\Users\Hogar\Desktop\javascript\curso javascript nuevo\04-Todo\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:47:19)
    at mergeChainOpts (C:\Users\Hogar\Desktop\javascript\curso javascript nuevo\04-Todo\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:320:26)
    at C:\Users\Hogar\Desktop\javascript\curso javascript nuevo\04-Todo\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:283:7
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    Entrypoint undefined = ./index.html
    [0] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html 2.76 KiB {0} [built]
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! webpack-inicial@1.0.0 build: `webpack --config webpack.prod.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the webpack-inicial@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Hogar\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-16T18_58_35_507Z-debug.log
```

alguien por favor sabria de algun comando o solución a este problema, no domino esto de git y github.

Comment: esto no tiene que ver con `git` webpack no está encontrando un módulo cuando se hace el build deberías comprobar las rutas a tus archivos

Comment: como las compruebo?, disculpa mi ignorancia,

Comment: a ver tu configuración de `webpack.prod.js`

Comment: ¿Nos puedes compartir el contenido del archivo `./src/index.js`?

Comment: A veces, la compilación falla cuando la ruta a tu proyecto se encuentra con nombres de carpetas (directorios) que contienen espacios. en tu código se ve que tu proyecto pertenece o se encuentra en una carpeta llamada: `curso javascript nuevo`. Te sugiero que lo renombres a algo como: `curso_javascript_nuevo` (usando guión bajo) o simplemente `cursojsnuevo`.  No digo que este sea el error exacto, pero me he encontrado con algunos casos donde sí lo es. Saludos